# Rich Text Editor supporting Table, Image and File Uploads

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, rich-text-editor

I am looking for a open source Rich Text Editor which supports table, images, file uploads and is as light as possible. Popular RTE like [tinymce](/questions/tagged/tinymce) or [ckeditor](/questions/tagged/ckeditor) are too big and there is no image and file upload support.

Comment: I briefly checked the websites of tinyMCE and CKEditor, both offer file uploads using plugins. Maybe these plugins are not for free.

Comment: @Nick... Yes they are not free

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few weeks ago I started using elrte.org  with  elrte.org/elfinder,
Its not perfect but is easy to implement and feature heavy.

#### 3rd party edit

It seems that elrte.org is no longer the place to get the editor. On [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/elrte/) it can still be downloaded **but** the last update was in 2013.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually full answer to your question, but about 6 months ago I was solving the same problem. And I end up writing my own RTE using heavily Jquery and for uploading flash plugin (more files at once). Table support is a little bit tricky so I didn't implement that, but planning in future.

If you don't need all the functionality of big RTE, you can use ContentEditable attribute and build some controls around it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice... Although I dont want to jump to developing my own RTE, Why reinvent the wheel? Lets hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Well, I was thinking the same. Reinventing the wheel is bad practise. But I spend a lot of time searching for tinyMCE/CK editor alternative and found none usable. And because they are not ideal for some usa-cases I went to develop my own RTE. It was a lot of work, but in long run it was a good choice. I have very flexible RTE which I can modify for my needs very easily.

Comment: If that would be the only option left, I would not backdown from it.:D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know [tinymce](/questions/tagged/tinymce), but [ckeditor](/questions/tagged/ckeditor) is not too big because it's made with plugins. I think it's easier built a image plugin or built one you need.

Comment: Image and Plugin... have to be bought seperately in order to use them

Comment: Yes I know but if you know javascript it's easy create a "image plugin"